# How can I find the length l on this cul de sac?

Tags: geometry

I need to redraw this [Cul de sac](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cul-de-sac) using autocad. I can do it if I know the value of l (which is the red l) but I cant think of how to obtain that value.

Also the angle of 55 degrees produces a length of 92.35. Can one use the proportion to find the angle that creates the 95.58 side?

Here is the cul de sac

[image: http://imgur.com/eipEjaU]

Answer (score 1):

For the angle consider the right-angled triangle formed by a radius, the bisector of the angle and half the chord:

$$sin(a/2) = (c/2) / r$$

For finding $l$:

Let the point $C$ be the top point in the drawing, at the end of the first radius, and $D$ the other end of the length $l$ which you are looking for. Let $E$ be the foot of the perpendicular on $BD$ through $C$

BEC is a right angled triangle, you know the hypotenuse $BC$ and you can find the angle at $B$. 
This lets you find the length of both $BE$ and $CE$.

Split the quadrilateral EDAC in a rectangle and a right angled triangle.
From the right angled triangle you know one (the vertical) leg and the hypotenuse. Determine the other leg, which has the same length as DE. The length $l$ you search is the total of $BE$ and $DE$.[image]